# rails HABTM to has many through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many-through, has-and-belongs-to-many, single-table-inheritance, sti

```
class QuestionSet
  has_and_belongs_to_many :questions,
                      class_name: 'Exam',
                      join_table: 'question_question_sets',
                      foreign_key: 'question_set_id',
                      association_foreign_key: 'question_id'

end

class Question
  has_and_belongs_to_many :question_sets,
                      class_name: 'Exam',
                      join_table: 'question_question_sets',
                      foreign_key: 'question_id',
                      association_foreign_key: 'question_set_id'

end
```

The above models are inherited from the base model `Exam`(using rails STI) and the join table contains two fields: `question_id` and `question_set_id`. Now I need to convert this association into `has_many through`.

I have tried as follows:

```
class QuestionQuestionSet
  has_many :questions
  has_many :question_sets 
end

class Question
  has_many :question_question_sets, foreign_key: :question_id
  has_many :question_sets, through: :question_question_sets 
end

class QuestionSet
  has_many :question_question_sets, foreign_key: :question_set_id
  has_many :questions, through: :question_question_sets 
end
```

Comment: Please show what you have tried on your own before asking someone to do  it for you.

Comment: I was playing around with class name and foreign_key. But nothing worked for me

Comment: updated my question, please have a look at it

Comment: I'm asking for database schema. You can find it here: `db/schema.rb`

Comment: create_table "question_question_sets", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "question_id"
    t.integer  "question_set_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",         null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",         null: false
  end

Answer (score 2):

Even after editing your models, it's necessary to create a new join table since the previous one (created by habtm) doesn't have and "id" column.
As a reference you can follow the steps indicated in http://www.chrisrolle.com/en/blog/migration-path-from-habtm-to-has_many-through